# If Loop to find the latest value from multiple textboxes from one form to populate another textbox is another form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a form called "Label" and another form called "Sheeter".
Sheeter form has 12 textboxes (Pallet1), (Pallet2), (Pallet3)...

The user will enter other details in the "Sheeter" form, but they will stay on the page till all the 12 boxes are filled up. Pallet textboxes basically captures the time at which the different pallets are made (which is for used as tracking numbers). As soon as one Pallet is made User will double click the textbox "Pallet1" and it will be populated with current time. Next the user wants to use this value in textbox Pallet1 to print a label. I have made a button which will fetch the value of Pallet1 textbox in a textbox in Label Form.
The user doesn't want to close the Sheeter form at this point, and will wait on the form till the next Pallet is produced, again double click on the textbox "Pallet2" to get the time and expect that once the Print button is clicked it takes the new value to populate the textbox label on form label.

I have tried if loops of two different types, however I am unsure of the syntax.

First logic is to see if a textbox is empty and if its true fetch the value from the previous textbox for the label.

Second logic is to compare the value of the textboxes and which is higher, fetch that value.

```
If Me.Pallet2.Value = "" Then
 
Forms![LabelSHEETER1].Pallet = Me.Pallet1
Me.JOB.SetFocus

Else
If Me.Pallet3.Value = Null Then
 
Forms![LabelSHEETER1].Pallet = Me.Pallet2
Me.JOB.SetFocus


Else

If Me.Pallet4.Value = Null Then
 
Forms![LabelSHEETER1].Pallet = Me.Pallet3
Me.JOB.SetFocus

End If
End If
End If
```

---

```
If Me.Pallet2.Value ="" Then
 
Forms![LabelSHEETER1].Pallet = Me.Pallet1
Me.JOB.SetFocus

Else
If Me.Pallet2.Value >Me.Pallet1.value Then
 
Forms![LabelSHEETER1].Pallet = Me.Pallet2
Me.JOB.SetFocus


Else

If Me.Pallet3.Value >Me.Pallet2.value Then
 
Forms![LabelSHEETER1].Pallet = Me.Pallet3
Me.JOB.SetFocus

End If
End If
End If
```

I am unsure if I should write "" or Null, have tried both, none of them work.

Also neither of the logic seem to be working (dont know if syntax is incorrect or logic itself is flawed)

Answer (score 0):

Oh wait, I found the solution:

```
If IsNull(Me.Pallet2.Value) Then
```

Forms![LabelSHEETER1].Pallet = Me.Pallet1
Me.JOB.SetFocus

Else

If IsNull(Me.Pallet3.Value) Then

Forms![LabelSHEETER1].Pallet = Me.Pallet2
Me.JOB.SetFocus

Else

If IsNull(Me.Pallet4.Value) Then

Forms![LabelSHEETER1].Pallet = Me.Pallet3
Me.JOB.SetFocus

End If
End If
End If

Comment: I found the solution, however the code is lengthy. I am sure I can shorten it by using some sort of if loop to do iterations to find empty textbox and fetch the value from the previous one.